# Ckeditor file editor_gecko.css not loading from AWS S3

Tags: amazon-s3, firefox, ckeditor

So, I am running a Django 2.2 python 3.9 app and using CKeditor4. All works find when loading the ckeditor locally on both Chrome and Firefox. No problem loading the editor_gecko.css from the local media directory.

Once I push code up to Heroku, it works fine on Chrome but from Firefox the editor box quickly disappears as soon as its loaded.

From Firefox inspection it looks like this file does not load from S3 while all other Ckeditor files load correctly.

```
s3-bucket/ckeditor/ckeditor/skins/moono-lisa/editor_gecko.css?t=K5H9
```

I confirmed that the editor_gecko.css is in the directory. (not sure what the t=K5H9 is about). I thought it was a permissions issue but set that file to ACL=public.

Console shows the following:

```
A resource is blocked by OpaqueResponseBlocking, please check browser console for details.
```

Again, it works great from S3 in Chrome. I did go into the FF config and turned off OpaqueResponseBlocking but that did not solve the issue.

Any clues would be great. Hoping not have to switch editors.